# getting null from getTag listview ontouchlistener android

Tags: java, android, listview, tags

I am trying to get the tag that I added on my custom adapter getView but the thing is it gives me null when I am trying to retrieve it

Here is the code from the getView of my custom adapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.pull_refresh_list_item, null);
             v.setTag(position);

        }

        RouteSummaryForStop i  = null;

        synchronized(methodLocker) {
            i = bussData.get(position);
        }

        if (i != null) {
                TextView bd = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bus_destination);
                TextView bn = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.bus_number);
               ;
                    bn.setWidth(154);

                bd.setText(i.getRouteHeading());
                bn.setText(i.getRouteNo());

        }


        return v;

    }
```

here is the code when I try to get it from the ontouchlistener of the listView:

```
result_list.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener() {
            private float startX;
            private float startY;
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    startX = event.getX();
                    startY = event.getY();
                    Log.d("tag", ""+v.getTag());
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                    float endX = event.getX();
                    float endY = event.getY();
                    if (isAClick(startX, endX, startY, endY)) { 
                        Log.d("click", "clicked");   
                        Log.d("tag", ""+v.getTag());
                        MainActivity.result_list.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
                        checkClicked = true;
                    }else{
                        MainActivity.result_list.setSoundEffectsEnabled(false);
                        checkClicked = false;
                        if(isASwipe(startX, endX, startY, endY)){   
                            Log.d("tag", ""+(TextView)v.getTag());
                            MainActivity.drawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
                        }else{

                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

EDIT+++++

I tried it inside the getview but it only capture the ACTIONDOWN:

```
v.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        private float startX;
        private float startY;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();
                Log.d("tag", "DOWN");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
                float endX = event.getX();
                float endY = event.getY();
                Log.d("click", "UP");   
                if (isAClick(startX, endX, startY, endY)) { 
                    Log.d("click", "UP");    
                }else{
                    if(isASwipe(startX, endX, startY, endY)){   
                        Log.d("tag", "SWIPE");
                    }else{

                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you post the stack trace

Comment: @Raghunandan There is no error. But the  Log.d("tag", ""+v.getTag()); always give me null

Comment: @Raghunandan it works but I want it to be in ontouch so I can swipe it.

Comment: if you want to swipe you can check the sample in the sdk or from here http://graphics-geek.blogspot.in/search?updated-max=2013-07-12T09:08:00-07:00&max-results=7. listview swipe to delete

Answer (score 1):

try setting onTouchListener to convertView in adapter class.

Comment: @Raghunandan I tried but it only capture the actiondown check the edit

Comment: post your modified Adapter class

Answer (score 0):

check the instance of View you are getting in onTouchListener().
as you have set onTouchListener to ListView, you will get instance of ListView in OnTouchListener, not an item in ListView.